# Cluster using virtual machine software with 2 workstations

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, cluster, benchmark, mysql-cluster

I want to do a benchmark between databases (MySQL Cluster, HBase and Cassandra). I need 8 nodes. I have 2 workstations Dual-processor Z600:

```
1. workstation1: 16 core - 16 Go RAM
2. workstation2: 8 core - 16 Go RAM
```

I would like to know if it's possible to use these workstations to make a cluster of 8 nodes by using a virtual machine software in Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Comment: What sort of spec of server would you be using to run these DB's on once you've decided which to go with?

Comment: I didn't know some nations use gigaoctets (Go). Nice, the bytes/bits is sometimes confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending what you want to achieve. Possible yes, but you likely have pathetic IO (which is generally a bottleneck for databases) and better make sure you split the VM's "strategically" because your network link between them is also very slow (likely: 1gb, clusters often run... faster. I have one here for our company and every server is connected to the switch with 200 gigabit).

Given ridiculous low amounts of RAM (actually lower than I would call a workstation in 2018 - those are computers, not workstations) you also will have problems simulating a production level larger database environment.

Good enough for some playing around, learning the technologies, testing setup - not good enough for testing a larger installation. Those machines are ancient.